Questions about calling methods in the memory models of C # and Java
In C # and Java, each time a method is called, it is a new stack frame. Does that mean that from memory, these two methods are not the same, even if their contents are the same
When it comes to dependency injection, I used Singleton instead of Transient because I believe it is stateless for services and using singleton injection should result in higher performance. Moreover, methods are stored in the method area and every call will enter the stack frame. However, my colleague told me that this would affect performance, so I had some doubts.

there are different needs for scoped, transistent and singleton Singleton - One instance of a resource, reused anytime it's requested.
Scoped - One instance of a resource, but only for the current request. New request (i.e. hit an API endpoint again) = new instance
Transient - A different instance of a resource, everytime it's requested.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67206763/when-to-use-following-transient-scoped-and-singleton

Local variables are allocated and stored on the stack, so each call will have a separate set of variables. Though the compiler may optimise your code further, such that variables only exist in CPU registers. Allocating a stack frame is as simple as incrementing the CPU's stack register, it's as cheap or cheaper than i++;.

It is not really clear what you are asking about, or how dependency injection are related to stack frames, or how this relates to performance in your specific case. If you have performance concerns of any kind, start by measuring.

You are overthinking. Methods in runtime memory, DI, and app functionality are on absolutely different levels of abstractions. Singleton is better than Transient not because of methods in memory but because objects are not recreated again and again. Stop worrying about illusionary optimizations. Write clean code in the first place. When you face performance issue, only then investigate. But still, methods in memory is not the level where you want to dive into.
